# Android Studio wont start, Failed to create JVM

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.0, java-9

I am trying to start my Android Studio v2.0 but it wont start. i get this **error: Failed to create JVM: error code -6**.

`JVM path`: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9`

If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define `JAVA_HOME` variable in

> Computer >System Properties > System Settings > Enviorment Variables.

I have set `JAVA_HOME` variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9`

**How can I make it start/work ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you should use Java 8. I understood from comments that you are using Java 9.

Android studio need java 8. Try to install it and then change the `JAVA_HOME` to JDK 8.

Maybe it works. Because Java 9 is still unstable.

Comment: Worked with JDK 8! would have preferred that it had worked with jdk 9 though